# How could I validate dates correctly?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, date, joi

I'm using celebrate to validate dates but I can still add a start_date higher than the end_date, what could I do to prevent this behaviour? Also using the format like this returns the following error:

```
Unknown date format YYYY-MM-DD
```

What can I do to use the desired format?

```
routes.post(
  '/world_series',
  celebrate({
    [Segments.BODY]: Joi.object().keys({
      start_date: Joi.date().required(),
      end_date: Joi.date().format('YYYY-MM-DD').greater(Joi.ref('start_date')).required(),
      champion_id: Joi.string().required(),
      runners_up_id: Joi.string().required(),
    }),
  }),
  WorldSeriesController.create
);
```

Comment: moment js is a good library regarding date related operation. You can try to use that. 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment

Comment: The (minimal) celebrate documentation lists the allowed format strings [here](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/master/API.md#anyvalidatevalue-options), allowed values are date, iso, string, time, utc. The associated notes show a poor understanding of dates in general and ECMAScript dates in particular. I've used [JSONschma](http://json-schema.org/draft-04/json-schema-core.html) previously, it seems to work OK and allows more options with validation. There are lots of tools online for creating and testing schemas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading the documentation I saw that I could use the ruleset to solve my problem, here's the code:

```
routes.post(
  '/world_series',
  celebrate({
    [Segments.BODY]: Joi.object().keys({
      start_date: Joi.date().required(),
      end_date: Joi.date()
        .ruleset.greater(Joi.ref('start_date'))
        .rule({ message: 'end_date must be greater than start_date' })
        .required(),
      champion_id: Joi.string().required(),
      runners_up_id: Joi.string().required(),
    }),
  }),
  WorldSeriesController.create
);
```